# Why do li elements with margin change my column layout in Firefox on hover?

Tags: css

On this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9v38rju6/3/), whenever I hover the cursor over an element in the second column, Firefox 87 on Windows starts switching back and forth between two renderings of the list, very rapidly.

Lower right panel must be ~850px wide to reproduce bug.

This does not happen under Chrome (or Edge).

The problem disappears when I comment the rule

```
li {
  margin: 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Not reproducible on my end, same version.

Comment: @SuperStormer Change the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, this is because you change the height of the border AND the margin-bottom on `:hover`!

Some browsers change the layout on an specific point (what is in your hand, with CSS) and could get ugly like your problem here.

If you hover over one of there links, the height of the link grows 2px more *(because of border-bottom-width 3px instead of 1px)* and the entire list-element also grows 2px. Now the browser has to "re-render" the layout of your list and height of elements. Also,
**you reset the margin-bottom from `0.5em` to `-2px`.**

This does not remove 2px from the margin-bottom, this set the margin-bottom to 2px! Could be kind of confusing.

```css
ul.index {
   columns: 15em;
}

li {
  margin: 0.25em 0 0.5em;
}


a[href] {
  text-decoration: underline;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

a[href]:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="index">
     <li><a href="#">@bottom-center</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@bottom-left</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@bottom-left-corner</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@bottom-right</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@bottom-right-corner</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@charset</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@color-profile</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@counter-style</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@custom-media</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@custom-selector</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@font-face</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@font-feature-values</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@font-palette-values</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@@hasinstance</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@import</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@@isconcatspreadable</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@keyframes</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@layer</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@left-bottom</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@left-middle</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@left-top</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@media</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">media</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@nest</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@page</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@property</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@right-bottom</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@right-middle</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@right-top</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@scope</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@scroll-timeline</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@supports</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@top-center</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@top-left</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@top-left-corner</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@top-right</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@top-right-corner</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@@toprimitive</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@@tostringtag</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@viewport</a>
     </li><li><a href="#">@-webkit-keyframes</a>
    </li></ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens as the margin changes the height of the element and the item does not suit into the first column anymore.

It does not happen if you remove the margin from either top or bottom for each `li` element like this:

```
li {
  margin: 0.25em 0 0 0;
}
```

or

```
li {
  margin: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}
```

Not sure why, but it happens with 2 and 3 columns.

I think I could work around it by using padding instead, like this:

```
li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

This way, the element height remains the same as the padding applies to the inner of the li element, not to the outside as the margin does.

Comment: Is there a reason why the bug only appears with Firefox?

Comment: Good question. I have read the specs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns quickly, but could not find any reason. Maybe someone else knows. I found a potential workaround and updated my post.

Comment: I got be bug on Edge. It depends on the heights - whether there is just enough room for the expanded border or not.